# Content using all available space with jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have a project with jQuery Mobile + phonegap and I have some issues with the footer and content div.

A basic jQuery Mobile page looks like this:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="map">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="inline">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
        <h1>MAP</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="map_canvas">
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d">
        <h4>TEST</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Now I'm trying to load google maps in the content so I use this in JavaScript:

```
$('div').live("pageshow", function()
{
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions); 
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Page with footer after content]

The problem is that the footer doesn't stick to the bottom unless you specify the attribute `data-position="fixed"` like this:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="d" data-position="fixed">
    <h4>TEST</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

That's fine but the problem is the map is loading before jquery mobile take the footer to the bottom, as a result I have this page:

[image: Page with footer fixed]

Where you can see the map only using the space left before it's moved to the bottom.

My question is.. what event should I wait for or what do I need to add to my code in order to load the map so it will use all the space between header and footer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need to wait for an event, you need to set the `.ui-content` element's height to something around `100%`.

Here is a purely CSS method of achieving `100%` height for a jQuery Mobile pseudo-page:

```
/*make sure the viewport is 100% height*/
html, body {
    height : 100%;
}

/*make the page element 100% height*/
#map-page {
    height : 100%;
}

/*specify a height for the header so we can line-up the elements, the default is 40px*/
#map-page .ui-header {
    height : 40px;
}

/*set the content to be full-width and height except it doesn't overlap the header or footer*/
#map-page .ui-content {
    position : absolute;
    top      : 40px;
    right    : 0;
    bottom   : 30px;
    left     : 0;
}

/*absolutely position the footer to the bottom of the page*/
#map-page .ui-footer {
    position : absolute;
    bottom   : 0;
    left     : 0;
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 30px;
}​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/J9uf5/2/

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for you suggestion. If I use all that CSS the application get crazy and doesn't work properly.. but if I only add this part: http://pastebin.com/JPUTjB0N it works beautifully with jQuery Mobile.. Please edit your answer to mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was looking for this for quite a long time.

Answer (score 7):

This  one also  works:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, height=device-height,
  initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,
  user-scalable=no;" />
</head>
<body>
    ....
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    ....
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    ....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice... as some added info for others:    

In browsers that support CSS position: fixed (most desktop browsers, iOS5+, Android 2.2+, BlackBerry 6, and others), toolbars that use the "fixedtoolbar" plugin will be fixed to the top or bottom of the viewport, while the page content scrolls freely in between. In browsers that don't support fixed positioning, the toolbars will remain positioned in flow, at the top or bottom of the page.

To enable this behavior on a header or footer, add the data-position="fixed" attribute to a jQuery Mobile header or footer element.

Answer (score 5):

Just add this css:

```
<style>
    #map{
        height: 0;
    }

    #map_canvas {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        text-shadow: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I don't get why making the parent height 0 and wanted child 100% makes this work, but this works great.